# Can tungsten replicator connect to sqlserver through ODBC and standard SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, replication, heterogeneous

Tungsten appears to support ODBC connections, but it's not clear if a connection to sqlserver would work.  Any thoughts?

I want to have sqlserver as the source, and MySQL as the destination.  Drop and replace all data might be fine.

If not tungsten, any other tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Navicat Premium**
link: http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html

I used to copy data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL
It accepts DB: `MySQL` , `PostgreSQL` , `Oracle` , `SQLite` and `SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

I have used linked servers as a way of sharing data between mysql and SqlServer and then have triggers from the sqlServer to the mysql linked server.

if the triggers will not work for you, the other better option will be to setup replication between the sqlserver and the mysql linked server.

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/